# How to add sliding banner in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-template

I am trying to add sliding banner to Joomla 2.5 but haven't had any success.

I have tried `magicslideshow` but it also did not work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you got a website example for what you call "sliding banner" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a slideshow :

[Avatar Slide Galleria](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/slideshow/image-jquery-slideshow/21117) and [demo website](http://joomavatar.com/demos/j16/index.php/slide-show-imagecontent/avatar-slide-galleria).

[JM Responsive Slideshow](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/slideshow/image-jquery-slideshow/24381) and [demo website](http://demo.joomlaman.com/extensions/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1&extension_id=22&Itemid=102).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try [Hot Image Slider](http://www.hotjoomlatemplates.com/free-joomla-extensions/20-hot-image-slider-free-jquery-image-slider). It's not too complicated to configure it. There are modules versions for all Joomla versions.

The PRO version of the same module [Responsive Joomla Slider](http://www.hotjoomlatemplates.com/joomla-extensions/250-responsive-joomla-slider) will be useful especially if you run a responsive website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Slideshow CK module for sliding image](http://www.joomlack.fr/extensions-joomla/slideshow-ck)